# CLion contexts and CMakeCache

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am running into the problem of easily switching between Debug and Release builds of my projects in CLion. After looking around, I found that in 2016, the system was changed and many users ran into trouble. However, none of the fixes that were suggested helped me.

Under Settings / Cmake, I entered two profiles, Release and Debug. However, in both the configuration selection at the top right of the editor and the context selection at the bottom right of the editor, only the first of the two profiles is available.

Also, the first profile seems to work fine with CMake, whereas for the second one I get an error message:

```
Cannot generate 'Debug' into /home/foo/code/cmake-build-debug
CMakeCache.txt is found in the project dir, only in-source generation will be performed.

[Failed to reload]
```

Comment: After configure the project *in-source* (with build directory equal to source one), you cannot configure the project *out-of-source* until you remove CMake configuration files, like `CMakeCache.txt`, from the source dir.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what that means. I am just using CLion and don't do anything manually. I already tried deleting CMakeCache.txt but it is re-generated.

Comment: Hm, I am not expert in CLion, but, as `CMakeCache.txt` is regenerated in the source dir, it looks like you have setup CLion to perform *in-source* build (with the build directory equal to the source one).

Comment: @starbal The question was "How do I fix this error?". This can in general be assumed for SO "questions" which don't pose an explicit question but describe some problem or error occurring.

Answer (score 2):

**!! please backup your project before applying my instructions !!**

I have got the same problem after adding new target to the CMakeLists.txt

To solve this error:

> Cannot generate 'Release' into .....`<path>`.....
>   CMakeCache.txt is found in the project dir, only in-source generation will be performed.

I delete folders **cmake-build-*** and **CMakeCache.txt**

After it I have got next error (or something like this):

> Error cmake cache

To solve this error I just **restart the clion**.
Also sometimes I press **`File` -> `Reload CMake Project`**, but visually nothing happends.

As result I have got workable project.

Comment: this is the solution worked for me