# CMakeCache.txt is found in the project dir, only in-source generation will be performed

Tags: clion

I get the following error message in CLion IDE.

```
Cannot generate 'Release' into /home/jdoe/project/cmake-build-release
CMakeCache.txt is found in the project dir, only in-source generation will be performed.
```

Nothing in Google helps me using the following keywords:

- [Search same error message in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=CMakeCache.txt%20is%20found%20in%20the%20project%20dir%2C%20only%20in-source%20generation%20will%20be%20performed)
- [Search same error message in blog.jetbrain.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP?q=CMakeCache.txt%20is%20found%20in%20the%20project%20dir,%20only%20in-source%20generation%20will%20be%20performed.).
- [JetBrain YouTrack search](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP?q=CMakeCache.txt%20is%20found%20in%20the%20project%20dir,%20only%20in-source%20generation%20will%20be%20performed.)

What is the best way to resume being able to make CLion start using CMakeFiles.txt again (without doing the painful but obvious way of recreating a new project)?

Side note: Any tip on how to improve search of this error message is also welcome.

[Update 1] There is a "non-answer" in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49656740/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the only reliable workaround to that thorny CLion cmake problem.

### Workaround

The brutal workaround is to perform:

1. Delete all `cmake-build-*`
2. Delete `CMakeCache.txt`
3. From CLion IDE, unload CMake by going to `Tools` menu item, `CMake` submenu item, and clicking on `Unload CMake project`.
4. Then head over to a different panel, the `Project` left navigation panel, right-click on `CMakeFiles.txt` to bring up context menu. Select 'Load CMake project`.

Also tracking this specific bug at JetBrain (maker of CLion) YouTrack [bug tracking](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/CPP-16917) website.

Comment: I renamed my CMakeFiles.txt to CMakeFiles2.txt. Then did steps 1 and 2, then renamed it back to CMakeFiles.txt and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have my work always sitting in a git repo.

I typically create a new folder and do `git init` right away to facilitate my work.

I worked around this issue by doing :
`git clean -fdx`

Comment: And how is that related to the question, if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and noticed the `Generation path` under `Settings > CMake > Build,Execution,Deployment` was set to `.`

Changing this to the default path, i.e `cmake-build-debug` and calling `Reset Cache and Reload Project` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by disabling rsync in `Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment > Remote Development`, for the project.

I was using `rsync`(3.2.9) from brew on macOS. Uninstalling it solved the issue too. The stock rsync (2.6.9) works fine.