# CLion says: "Cannot generate into /the/project/dir, it is already used for unknown project"

Tags: cmake, clion, buildconfiguration

I've been using CLion with a certain repository of mine for a while now. Suddenly (or maybe not suddenly, but I can't figure out the cause), I get this error  message in the CMake console:

```
Cannot generate into /path/to/the/project/dir
It is already used for unknown project

Please either delete it manually or select another generation directory
```

I tried several things:

- Deleting the build directories
- Deleting .idea and opening the directory as a new project
- Ensuring there are no other instances of CLion in the background
- Checking the file ownership and permissions

... but to no effect. However, cloning the repository into a new folder does not result in this situation.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Notes:

- CLion 2022.1 EAP 3
- Devuan GNU/Linux Chimaera (~= Debian Bullseye)
- non-root user

Comment: Are you using multiple builds eg Debug/Release? It seems like there are some issues with that (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49656740/clion-contexts-and-cmakecache). I was able to solve a similar issue by deleting the build files and CMakeCache and then invalidating caches and restarting.

Comment: @soothsooth: I was using different build configurations, yes. But I'm not experiencing the issue right now...

Comment: Since you have the privilege of access to your machine, could you try producing steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @starball: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it right now. Almost a year has passed... I must have done something to make it go away.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem. Deleting `CMakeCache.txt` in the project (root) directory did the trick for me.

Comment: CMakeCache in which (sub)directory?

Comment: In the root in my case, which is also the directory with `CMakeLists.txt`.